# Serializer / Deserializer for OffsetDateTime in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I've created a Serializer / Deserializer for OffsetDateTime in a Spring Boot v1.5.14.RELEASE app. First I create a custom constraint annotation:

```
@Primary
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        simpleModule.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new JsonSerializer<OffsetDateTime>() {
            @Override
            public void serialize(OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                jsonGenerator.writeString(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.format(offsetDateTime));
            }
        });

        simpleModule.addDeserializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new  JsonDeserializer<OffsetDateTime>() {
            @Override
            public OffsetDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                return DateUtils.convertToOffsetDateTime(jsonParser.getValueAsString());
            }
        });

        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

        return objectMapper;
    }
```

in the response I see the value correctly formatted, but on the request I got this error

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.OffsetDateTime' for property 'fromDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat java.time.OffsetDateTime] for value '2019-01-01'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2019-01-01]]
```

and

```
public static OffsetDateTime convertToOffsetDateTime (String date) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(DateFormat.TIME_ZONE_ID);
        ZoneOffset currentOffsetForMyZone = zoneId.getRules().getOffset(Instant.now());
        return OffsetDateTime.of( parseLocalDate(date),LocalTime.NOON, currentOffsetForMyZone);
    }
```

and I think the Deserializer is not even called because I added this to throw an Exception, but no exception is throw...

```
        public OffsetDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            int m = 9 /0 ;
            return DateUtils.convertToOffsetDateTime(jsonParser.getValueAsString());
        }


public static LocalDate parseLocalDate(String  strDate) {
        return LocalDate.parse(strDate, DateFormat.DATE_FORMATTER);
    }
```

and the bean:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class HotelData {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private OffsetDateTime fromDate;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private OffsetDateTime toDate;

}
```

and

```
public final class DateFormat {

    public static final String DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    public static final String TIME_ZONE_ID = "Africa/Brazzaville";
    public static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern(DATE_PATTERN)
            .withZone(ZoneId.of(TIME_ZONE_ID));

    private DateFormat(){}
}
```

and the problem is on testing:

```
 mockMvc.perform(get("/hotel")
                .param("hotelId", "1338767")
                .param("fromDate", "2019-01-01")
                .param("toDate", "2019-05-21")
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: Can you also share the `parseLocalDate()` method? Just to make sure that the parsing isn't actually causing the issue.

Comment: Can you also share `DateFormat.DATE_FORMATTER` and `DateFormat.TIME_ZONE_ID`? We won't be able to reproduce the issue if we don't know all code related to the parsing.